# MySQL all the variable not passing the data

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem with send variable data to mysql, one of my variable is passing but other is not.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["PAT_ID"])){
ob_start();
header("location: login.php");
ob_end_flush(); 
}

$patient_id ="";
$complainID = "";

$patient_id = $_SESSION["PAT_ID"];

if(isset($_GET["ComplainID"])){

$complainID = $_GET["ComplainID"];
}

include "config/connect_to_mysql.php";
?>

<?php 
//Diesease photo\

echo "Hello Patient Your Complain ID: " . $complainID;

$imageerr = "";
$typeerr = "";
$sizeerr = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

 if( (isset($_FILES['galleryField_1']) && $_FILES['galleryField_1']['error'] == 0)
    || (isset($_FILES['galleryField_2'])) 
        || (isset($_FILES['galleryField_3']))
            || (isset($_FILES['galleryField_4'])) 
   ){

        $allowedExts = array("JPEG", "jpeg", "jpg", "JPG");
        $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["galleryField_1"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($temp);

        if ((
           ($_FILES["galleryField_1"]["type"] == "image/JPEG")
        || ($_FILES["galleryField_1"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["galleryField_1"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($_FILES["galleryField_1"]["type"] == "image/JPG"))
        && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){



            if($_FILES['galleryField_1']['size'] > 1048576) { //1 MB (size is also in bytes)

                $sizeerr = "Photo must be within 1 MB";

            } else{ 

              // Add this image into the database now

              $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shasthojito`.`sdispic` (`sdis_pic_id`, `pat_id`,        `comp_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$patient_id', '$complainID')") 
                   or die (mysql_error());

              $gallery_id = mysql_insert_id();
              // Place image in the folder 
              $newgallery = "$gallery_id.jpg";

              move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['galleryField_1']['tmp_name'], "dpic/$newgallery");

                }
        }else{
            $typeerr = "You have to put JPEG Image file";
        }
    }else{
            $imageerr = "No Image Selected";
    }
```

Here the variable $patientID is working fine and passing the data into it, but the $complainID is not working on sql query but its showing the value in echo ...

Comment: I guess you are doing POST but trying to get the `$complainID` as GET

Comment: Before proceeding: Read this - why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php and get clear about basics like REQUEST, GET and POST

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, I agree with you..@mhtamum please check..becauze your code seems good.

Comment: No I am getting from the URL

Answer (score 1):

Your are mixing `GET` with `POST` Since you're using this line:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

You need to change this:

```
if(isset($_GET["ComplainID"])){

$complainID = $_GET["ComplainID"];
}
```

To:

```
if(isset($_POST["ComplainID"])){

$complainID = $_POST["ComplainID"];
}
```

**Or** maybe you only need to change this:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

To:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
```

Be sure about the method you are using to transfer date to your actual file.

**EDIT 1:**

Following your answers through your comments above, please change this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shasthojito`.`sdispic` (`sdis_pic_id`, `pat_id`,        `comp_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$patient_id', '$complainID')") 
                   or die (mysql_error());
```

To:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `shasthojito`.`sdispic` (`sdis_pic_id`, `pat_id`,        `comp_id`) VALUES (NULL, '$patient_id', '".$complainID."')") 
                   or die (mysql_error());
```

**EDIT 2:**

Before inserting the variable, be sure it is of the same type as the column `comp_id` of your table:

```
if (isset($_GET['ComplainID']) && ctype_digit($_GET['ComplainID']))
{
  $complainID = $_GET["ComplainID"];
}
```

Comment: @mhtamun in that case perform the second change I mentioned (after **Or**)

Comment: @mhtamun so you receive that variable from URL and you are able to echo it after GETting it ?

Comment: @mhtamun Ok, I understand better your problem now. Can you tell me please what is the type of `comp_id`` in your table (database) ?

Comment: interger type length 11 in mysql

Comment: @mhtamun do you get any error ? if yes, can you display it please ? (the error from your original code)

Comment: @mhtamun strange ... what about if you remove that long white space in your query before `comp_id` ?